# When running azd init on the root of a Net Aspire project I'm receiving an error

Tags: .net, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

When I run `azd init`, I get the following error:

> ERROR: only a single Aspire project is supported at this time

[image]

Comment: did you find an solution?

Comment: @cyptus check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you try to run `azd init` from the solution folder.

It will give this error:

> ERROR: only a single Aspire project is supported at this time

You need to change the directory to have the Aspire project which typically has a name convention ending with projectName.**AppHost**.

Then run it from there it will work.

As you can see in this project example I have taken snapshots of. There are multiple projects, and one project is Aspire which ends with AppHost.

[image]

Now I will switch to it `cd WeatherApp.AppHost`, and run `azd init` again, it works:

[image]

I can not defend the reason if this is made on purpose like this or if there is a bug in the command line.

> Disclaimer: I have a simple aspire project working with azd command line example, you can check it on [GitHub](https://github.com/maythamfahmi/net-aspire-playground).

Comment: thanks, that works! off topic: which cli do you use to get these project infos printed? (e.g. WeatherApp.AppHost project)

Comment: It is powershell with Oh My Posh،